# There's something wrong with openpyxl, am i missing something crucial?

Tags: pandas, openpyxl, xlsx, conditional-formatting

I haven't updated any libraries from the last time i ran a script, that, in short is supposed to parse a huge CSV file, do some statistics on it and plot some select data, then compile it to an *.xlsx file, i was using the module "openpyxl" to add conditional formatting and the plots as images, for some reason both the conditional formatting and the images are gone, like the program itself draws them and imports them just fine in the workbook object, and adds the conditional formatting rules, doesn't raise any errors or warnings but when i open the export file they're just not there... except the conditional formatting that pandas automatically adds for column and index labels...

I tried installing older versions of pandas, openpyxl and even xlsxwriter, and using that instead but no dice...
I tried inspecting the workbook and worksheet objects prior to saving it, and the data IS there, just as i expected, it seems like it's not saved...

I tried using both the writer.save() and writer.close() methods interchangeably but the result was just the same...

for context here's the code that adds the images:

```
importedimage = openpyxl.drawing.image.Image(os.path.join(imgfolder_dir, element))
importedimage.anchor = column_indexer[int(str(ix).replace("_", "")) - 1] + "1"
importedimage.width = 900
importedimage.height = 360
worksheet.add_image(importedimage)
```

note the method i use:

```
worksheet.add_image(importedimage)
```

i've used this exact function for years and has always worked.

here's the code that adds the conditional formatting:

toplimit and bottomlimit are values depending on which, the cell should be colored green or red

```
REDTEXT = openpyxl.styles.Font(size=14, bold=False, color="9C0006")
REDBLOCK = openpyxl.styles.PatternFill(start_color="FFC7CE", end_color="FFC7CE", fill_type="solid")

# YELLOWTEXT = openpyxl.styles.Font(size=14, bold=False, color="9C6500")
# YELLOWBLOCK = openpyxl.styles.PatternFill(start_color="FFEB9C", end_color="FFEB9C", fill_type="solid")

GREENTEXT = openpyxl.styles.Font(size=14, bold=False, color="006100")
GREENBLOCK = openpyxl.styles.PatternFill(start_color="C6EFCE", end_color="C6EFCE", fill_type="solid")




GRAPHS.conditional_formatting.add(format_cell, cfRule=openpyxl.formatting.rule.CellIsRule(operator="greaterThanOrEqual", formula[toplimit], fill=REDBLOCK, font=REDTEXT))

GRAPHS.conditional_formatting.add(format_cell, cfRule=openpyxl.formatting.rule.CellIsRule(operator="lessThanOrEqual", formula=[bottomlimit], fill=REDBLOCK, font=REDTEXT))

GRAPHS.conditional_formatting.add(format_cell, cfRule=openpyxl.formatting.rule.CellIsRule(operator="lessThanOrEqual", formula=[toplimit], fill=GREENBLOCK, font=GREENTEXT))

GRAPHS.conditional_formatting.add(format_cell, cfRule=openpyxl.formatting.rule.CellIsRule(operator="greaterThanOrEqual", formula=[bottomlimit], fill=GREENBLOCK, font=GREENTEXT))
```

again, this has always worked.

the code that handles the file save:

```
writer = ExcelWriter(filename, engine="openpyxl")
writer.workbook = analysis_book
writer.worksheets = dict((ws.title, ws) for ws in analysis_book.worksheets)
base_worksheet = analysis_book.worksheets[0]
worksheet_0 = analysis_book.worksheets[1]
worksheet_1 = analysis_book.worksheets[2]
```

then, after adding all the data, the images and then the conditional formatting i call

writer.close()

i've tried using

pandas==1.3.3 > pandas (latest)
openpyxl==3.0.5 > openpyxl==3.1.1

but nothing changed

(it's an ancient project)